# \Latex{} : undefined control sequence

Tags: macros

I use `teXworks` and I have a file called `textwork1.ltx`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\title{My first \Latex{} Document}
\maketitle

Hello world!
\end{document}
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Errors: 1, Warnings: 0, Bad boxes: 0


textwork1.ltx
11
Undefined control sequence.
\@title ->My first \Latex 
                          {} Document
l.11 \maketitle
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: "does not show any research effort:" Please check _any_ documentation on LaTeX you have (or use Google) - it will clearly explain this error message.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I did my research. If you read the answer, you will see the next: LaTeX can be really murky with its errors. The control sequence is kind of command. This error doesn't reflect anything.

Comment: @user2579252: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Errors_and_Warnings#Undefined_control_sequence - it's my second hit on Google.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

LaTeX can be really murky with its errors. The control sequence is kind of *command*.

Thus it says, the parser did not understand/know the `\Latex` command. Perhaps you meant `\LaTeX`. The difference is capital `T` and `X`.